# which analysis fit the best for the data?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, biostatistics

I am trying to work on the data of my master thesis. I have to create a model, but I don't know which analysis perform. My data look like this

| number | ID | sp | ab | alt | SWdiv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 4 | 6 | 630 | 0.25802965 |
| 2 | A2 | 9 | 16 | 750 | 0.29235324 |
| 3 | A3 | 8 | 14 | 850 | 0.411620203 |
| 4 | A4 | 9 | 22 | 950 | 0.444079553 |
| 5 | A5 | 2 | 12 | 1050 | 0.294855765 |
| 6 | A6 | 13 | 40 | 1130 | 0.298451014 |
| 7 | B1 | 2 | 2 | 750 | 0.275329152 |
| 8 | B2 | 5 | 6 | 850 | 0.043352118 |
| 9 | B3 | 14 | 16 | 950 | 0 |
| 10 | B4 | 17 | 58 | 1050 | 0.230358688 |
| 11 | B5 | 7 | 9 | 1150 | 0.298759725 |
| 12 | B6 | 8 | 68 | 1250 | 0.012192474 |
| 13 | C1 | 12 | 20 | 830 | 0.467542842 |
| 14 | C2 | 13 | 19 | 930 | 0.454480722 |
| 15 | C3 | 6 | 30 | 1030 | 0.464584038 |
| 16 | C4 | 7 | 14 | 1130 | 0.448191833 |
| 17 | C5 | 5 | 15 | 1250 | 0.052045275 |
| 18 | C6 | 2 | 7 | 1315 | 0.051767368 |
| 19 | D1 | 3 | 3 | 650 | 0.294855541 |
| 20 | D2 | 11 | 17 | 750 | 0.291717599 |
| 21 | D3 | 9 | 46 | 850 | 0.084284864 |
| 22 | D4 | 8 | 57 | 950 | 0.088574421 |
| 23 | D5 | 4 | 32 | 1050 | 0.160873283 |
| 24 | D6 | 13 | 22 | 1150 | 0.297638962 |
| 25 | D7 | 6 | 22 | 1250 | 0.290733158 |
| 26 | E1 | 11 | 23 | 800 | 0.250878932 |
| 27 | E2 | 8 | 8 | 900 | 0.418021272 |
| 28 | E3 | 10 | 13 | 1000 | 0.132159303 |
| 29 | E4 | 5 | 10 | 1100 | 0.058487554 |
| 30 | E5 | 5 | 15 | 1200 | 0.250310822 |
| 31 | E6 | 10 | 19 | 1350 | 0.01600807 |
| 32 | F1 | 6 | 20 | 800 | 0.462497319 |
| 33 | F2 | 15 | 54 | 900 | 0.376552904 |
| 34 | F3 | 6 | 13 | 1000 | 0.298264791 |
| 35 | F4 | 6 | 13 | 1100 | 0.394736812 |
| 36 | G1 | 14 | 22 | 830 | 0.391455956 |
| 37 | G2 | 11 | 16 | 930 | 0.282922551 |
| 38 | G3 | 5 | 10 | 1030 | 0.282398234 |
| 39 | G4 | 10 | 15 | 1130 | 0.153502726 |
| 40 | G5 | 13 | 18 | 1230 | 0.051586706 |
| 41 | H1 | 10 | 11 | 700 | 0.3009609 |
| 42 | H2 | 7 | 14 | 800 | 0.579228102 |
| 43 | H3 | 5 | 11 | 900 | 0.528108703 |
| 44 | H4 | 20 | 48 | 1000 | 0.28689587 |
| 45 | H5 | 13 | 18 | 1100 | 0.264542772 |
| 46 | H6 | 10 | 20 | 1250 | 0.29928462 |
| 47 | I1 | 12 | 13 | 535 | 0.35326876 |
| 48 | I2 | 3 | 5 | 635 | 0.273947657 |
| 49 | I3 | 18 | 30 | 720 | 0.467208221 |
| 50 | I4 | 16 | 188 | 835 | 0.276669711 |
| 51 | I5 | 7 | 69 | 935 | 0.000867067 |
| 52 | L1 | 6 | 10 | 435 | 0.36910895 |
| 53 | L2 | 7 | 20 | 606 | 0.236700524 |
| 54 | L3 | 14 | 33 | 697 | 0.111132519 |
| 55 | L4 | 17 | 42 | 797 | 0.296757045 |
| 56 | L5 | 5 | 7 | 910 | 0.27539552 |
| 57 | L6 | 10 | 15 | 1000 | 0.29748451 |
| 58 | L7 | 6 | 11 | 1101 | 0.276755556 |

58 sample points each has two value: altitude and diversity index related to habitat heterogeneity. What I sample are different insects and I have two values: sp = species (total number of different species for each sample point) and ab = abundance (total number of insects for each sample point). My question are are the species richness or the abundance affected by the altitude or the habitat heterogeneity? which is the best analysis to perform? and why?

thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you please post te data sample as text, that is, a readable format. (the image now is so small fonts that I have difficulties reading it). Maybe also some more details, how many sampling points? How where they selected? About how many species ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen.i am gonna trying to simplifying the data to post. there are 58 sampling point divided in 10 transect, each transect cover at least 500 meter in difference in height with each sampling point on an altitude of 100 above the previous.
the number of species and the abundance is a count related to each sampling point and the sampling has been repeated 5 times.
Thank you very much

Comment: i edit the previous images i m sorry, i don't know how to copy paste the data to look like a table

Comment: So you have 5 line transects? species count is OK, but is abundancies really a count? Can you explain (with formulas) how you define abundance? Maybe show us some plots, for example, abundance along the transects (versus heights). It's not clear (for me at least) what should be a random effect, so I woud start with glm's. Maybe, as a starting point, Poisson regression (which means log link)

Comment: sorry i haven't been clear.
the sampling has been repeated 5 times in 5 different months, along 10 transect. Each transect consist of at least 5 point for a total of 58.
the abundance has been calculated by addition of how many number of each species  was found in each of the 58 point. so for example point A1 we found 4 different species, about those we found the first species 1 time the second two times the third 2 times and the fourth 1 times so our abundance was 6. @kjetilbhalvorsen I am going to produce a graphic and trying to post it. i Thought the random effect could be the 58 points

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly one of your questions is: is the altitude related to the richness of the species of this insect? In this question your independent variable is the altitude (continuous measurement), and your dependent variable is  the species richness (continuous measurement). You could answer this question with [linear regression](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/linreg.htm) .

Using linear regression, you could also add another predictor to the model (e.g. the abundance), to see if and how each variable influences your dependent variable.